# Azure Data Factory - Lookup Activity: Filtering Azure Table Storage query with In operator

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I created a Azure Table storage with this format:

| ID | Table |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | table1 |
| 2 | table2 |
| 3 | table3 |
| 4 | table4 |

and in the DataFactory I want to create a query using this table filtering with the IN operator, for example: `ID in ('1', '2')`

I'm using a Lookup Activity and I created this array parameter:
[array parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTHjf.png)

and I want to use it in the query, for example: `@ID in pipeline().parameters.Id`
image:
[data factory - lookup activity query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hue3W.png)

Does anyone know a way to filter and help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AFAIK**, Currently `IN` and `Contains` are **not supported** in Azure Table Storage Queries.

If your array values are less, you can directly give the query like `Id eq '1' or Id eq '2'` in lookup which will give the following result.

[image]

If your array is large, you can try the below approach using a ForEach.

**Lookup activity:**

[image]

**ForEach:**

Give the Lookup output value.

[image]

**Inside ForEach Store the `item()` in a variable as string:**

[image]

**Inside if condition give the following expression:**

```
@contains(pipeline().parameters.arr,item().Id)
```

Here `arr` is an array parameter with `["1","2"]` values.

[image]

**In true activities append the Variable value to an array variable:**

[image]

**Result stored in another variable from `res1` variable (optional and only for showing result here):**

[image]